# What does "Kunst und Bier gibt es allhier" mean?

Tags: translation

I have an old wine goblet, I think it's a wine goblet, that has raised figures of a woman holding a wreath over her head with an animal at her side, a family crest is next, a panoramic view of a city and below it is the word MUNCHEN, next looks like a priest.  The reason I think it's a wine goblet is the base has clusters of grapes and leaves.

It is a piece from my family that came from Germany in the mid 1800's.  I think Carl or Joseph Kobitz was someone in the church.  I would like to know what this goblet/chalice signifies.

Comment: Does it really say *Munchen*, not *München*? And is it *bier* and not *Bier*?

Comment: We are not translation service. You might want to [edit] and state what from your research you didn't understand.

Comment: This wouldn't be a pewter goblet like these, would it: http://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/vintage-pewter-goblets-kunst-und-bier-404156958

Comment: The priest is probably a *[monk](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/München#/media/Datei%3AMuenchen_Kleines_Stadtwappen.svg)*, the namesake of the city.

Comment: Yes, Carsten it is like the second spelling and Bier.  Sorry c.p.  I thought that's what this site was for.  YES, Mac it is the same.  Thank you Stephie for correcting it to monk.  Thank all of you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, *München* is a town in Bavaria. In English it is known as *Munich*. Then

> Kunst und Bier gibt es allhier.

(I have capitialised *Bier* according to modern orthography. I would think that this would also have been done in the 19th century, but I am not sure) simply means

> There is art and beer here.

The word *allhier* is an obsolescent variant of *hier* (*here*). The expression *es gibt*, literally *it gives*, means *there is*. German word order is different from English word order and more flexible. A word by word translation would be: * *Art and beer gives it here.* Note that *Bier* (pronounced similarly to the English *beer*) rhymes with *allhier*.